# Reading data from firebase realtime database and display as a list using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement the product list by following the video, but the list doesnt display the products that I have listed in the `firebase` database. Can someone help?

## product-form.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for ="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" value="c.$key">
                {{ c.name }}
            </option>
        </select>            
</div>
```

## product-form.component.ts

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  
  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) { 
    this.categories$= categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## category.service.ts

```
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }


  getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories');


  }
}
```

I have manually entered the categories in the firebase realtime database looks like this.
categories

[Categories in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh7Y2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @adrita, i tried your suggestion. The categories list are now populated with 3 empty values which wasnt displayed previously. However the names aren't displayed.

Comment: @IndrajitRavi It's probably because you've stored the names in the objects of the keys.

Comment: Could you log what `getCategories` returns in your component? I haven't used the Realtime Database so I'm not sure as to how your data is actually represented.

Comment: @Edric Thank you, i changed it from c.name to c.key in the product-form.html and the list got populated.